# Usare fugge o fugga

Tags: word-usage

Non posso capire perché il famoso proverbio ***`in amore vince chi fugge`*** contiene ***`fugge`*** invece di ***`fugga`***.

Mi sembra che c'e dovrebbe essere un ***congiuntivo*** li. Mi può spiegare quale il motivo per favore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel proverbio "chi fugge" è una proposizione subordinata relativa, che in questo caso rimpiazza il soggetto della principale ("In amore vince"). È più facile analizzarla se rimpiazziamo il pronome doppio *chi* con il sinonimo *colui che*, in cui si vede chiaramente la divisione dei ruoli ("colui"=soggetto della principale, "che"=pronome relativo, che si riferisce a colui). Analizziamo dunque "In amore vince colui che fugge".

In italiano le proposizioni relative possono essere costruite con l'indicativo, il congiuntivo, il condizionale o l'infinito.

In questo caso si tratta di una cosiddetta *relativa esplicativa*, vale a dire di una proposizione che specifica un componente della principale (in questo caso, il soggetto "colui"). Di solito le proposizioni relative esplicative vengono costruite con l'*indicativo*, a meno che non si voglia dare alla frase un senso di dubbio. Per esempio, in Serianni, *Grammatica* XIV.251

> L’indicativo è il modo di gran parte delle relative esplicative e delle relative limitative che enuncino un fatto in termini oggettivi, reali, descrittivi: il congiuntivo attribuisce alla frase una coloritura eventuale, accostandola a una finale, a una consecutiva o a una condizionale (ha invece
> l’indicativo la relativa con valore causale).

In questo caso il proverbio non vuole esprimere dubbi, per cui si usa l'indicativo.

Comment: Salve Denis, grazie mille per la spiegazione soddisfacente